# Getting my backbone views to load test data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

This is a new question but runs on from the last one, [Dynamically load my 'IDs' into my Backbone Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836706/dynamically-load-my-ids-into-my-backbone-collection)

I now have all my models getting the data from my database. Now I want to be able to load this data into a view. But for some reason I can not get any views to work at all, this is my current view code,

```
 var MyView= Backbone.View.extend({
   el: '.page',
   render: function() {
      this.$el.html('CONTENT HERE FROM BACKBONE');
      return this;
   }
 }); 

 var testView = new MyView({});

 $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $('.page').append(testView); 
 })
```

Now `'.page'` is a div tag with that class set up on my page. But will not output my test text above, so what am I doing wrong?

The main aim is to have this view load the data form the model, which is all working fine, but right now I can not even get this simple test to work?

Have I forgotten to do with starting up the view functions with backbone?

All help most welcome.

Glenn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can initialize `View` inside document ready, View automatically call his render function when in initialize state, but in your case since document dose not load completely in initialize state, it fail to render

```
var testView;

$(document).ready(function(){ 
     testView = new MyView 
});
```

Comment: I marked yours as the answer because I did change it to 'render()' like Manish said but it did not work until I move the var into the doc ready call. Many thanks Glenn

Answer (score 1):

testView is an instance of MyView. You should not be calling append with testView. You need to invoke render method on testView instance. Since MyView el element is .page, content will be append to .page.

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    testView.render(); 
})
```